# "no registration needed" or "no registration required"?

Tags: word-choice

Which of the following, should I write?

> 1. no registration needed
> 2. no registration required

I am trying to promote some web game to the people who see my ad (that they don't need to register before trying it out).

Comment: Maybe "No registration is required"

Comment: When space is limited (newspaper headlines, computer monitors, traffic signs, want ads), we often eliminate expendable words, like "is".

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatically correct. But "no registration required" is more commonly used. The following sentences can be used interchangeably:

> No login required
>
> No sign up required
>
> No registration required
>
> No registration needed

Answer (score 1):

Either is OK.

When you are faced with this kind of decision and you want to get it right, it is often the case that the oldest and shortest words are the best. Also, it is a good idea to avoid words with Latin and Greek roots and favour words with Germanic or Old English roots, since they tend to be simpler and easier to understand.

In your case, you have [need](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=need+etymology), which has a Germanic root, and [require](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=require+etymology), which has a Latin root.

I'd choose *needed*, but it's up to you.

Comment: How do I know which word has what root? Thanks!

Comment: Click on the links that I have provided. Alternatively, Google "*word-to-look-up* etymology"

Answer (score 0):

There is not so much difference, but the reader's perception may vary. You have to try to understand what their expectation is.

> no registration needed

This is rather informal and could be used in most situations. Some functions, such a downloading software or reading a blog, often do not require any registration. In these kinds of situations, this phrase is enough.

> no registration required

This should apply to situations where registration would normally be required, for example to get an email account. Your condition (not needed) would be considered exceptional and important for the customer to understand.